# The loop for 10 times is not working, displaying a text, and having an exception error in python

Tags: python, exception, text-files

My program wants to repeat it 10 times which I tried to do by putting in for i in range(10):, it doesnt do it 10 times

Also I need to have an exception error like if a user enters forty instead of 40, I can display "error, you must enter the value as an integer" but my cmd prompt says I have an inconsistent use of tabs and indentation.

my last one is that when I try to display my conversions to a text, it says the variable isn't defined which makes no sense... for example outfile.write(str(miles) + "\n"), my cmd prompt states that the name miles is not defined and i define miles in the code

Here's my code:

```
# constants for the menu choices
Mi_to_km_choice=1
F_to_C_choice=2
Gallons_to_liters_choice=3
Pounds_to_Kilograms_choice=4
Inches_to_Centimeters_choice=5
Quit_choice=6
 #open a new file named conversions.txt
outfile= open("conversions.txt" , "w")



#the main function
def converting():
 for i in range(10):
#a.converting Miles to Kilometers
 #choice variable controls the loop
  choice=0
  while choice != Quit_choice:
  #display the menu
   display_menu()

  #get the user's choice
   choice= int(input("Enter your choice:"))

  #perform the selected action
  #miles to km
   if choice == Mi_to_km_choice:
    counter = 1
    miles = int(input("Enter a value for miles "))
    while miles < 0: 
      print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles") 
      miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))
      counter+=1
      if counter > 3:
         break
    if counter <= 3:
       kilometers= miles * 1.6 
       print(miles , "miles is",  kilometers , "kilometers")
      except ValueError:
       print("Error: Miles must be an integer")

    else:
       print("You have the exceeded error count")

#b.converting Fahrenheit to Celsius
   elif choice == F_to_C_choice:
    counter = 1
    fahrenheit = int(input("Enter a value for fahrenheit ")) 
    while fahrenheit > 1000: 
      print("Error, you can't enter a value above 1000 degrees fahrenheit") 
      fahrenheit = eval(input("Enter the correct value for fahrenheit "))
      counter+=1
      if counter > 3:
         break
    if counter <= 3:
     celsius= (fahrenheit-32) * 5/9 
     print(fahrenheit , "degrees fahrenheit is",  celsius , "degrees celsius")
    else:
     print("You have exceeded the error count")

#c.converting Gallons to Liters
   elif choice == Gallons_to_liters_choice:
    counter=1
    gallons= int(input("Enter a value for gallons "))
    while gallons < 0:
       print("Error, you can't enter a negative for gallons")
       gallons = eval(input("Enter the correct value for gallons "))
       counter+=1
       if counter > 3:
          break
    if counter <= 3:
     liters= gallons * 3.9
     print(gallons , "gallons is", liters , "liters")
    else:
     print("You have exceeded the error count")

#d. converting Pounds to Kilograms
   elif choice == Pounds_to_Kilograms_choice:
    counter=1
    pounds= int(input("Enter a value for pounds "))
    while pounds < 0:
      print("Error, you can't enter a negative for pounds")
      pounds = eval(input("Enter the correct value for pounds "))
      counter+=1
      if counter > 3:
         break
    if counter <= 3:
     kilograms= pounds * .45
     print(pounds , "pounds is", kilograms , "kilograms")
    else:
     print("You have exceeded the error count")

#e.converting Inches to Centimeters
   elif choice == Inches_to_Centimeters_choice:
    counter=1
    inches= int(input("Enter a value for inches "))
    while inches < 0:
     print("Error, you can't enter a negative negative value for inches")
     inches=eval(input("Enter the correct value for inches "))
     counter+=1
     if counter > 3:
       break
    if counter <=3:
     centimeters= (inches * 2.54)
     print(inches, "inches is", centimeters, "centimeters")
    else:
     print("You have exceeded the error count")
   elif choice == Quit_choice:
    print("Exiting the program...")
   else:
    print("Error: invalid selection. ")

#display the menu
def display_menu():
 print("           Menu")
 print("1) Miles to Kilometers")
 print("2) Fahrenheit to Celsius")
 print("3) Gallons to Liters")
 print("4) Pounds to Kilograms")
 print("5) Inches to Centimeters")
 print("6) Quit") 

 #write the conversions to the file
 outfile.write(str(miles) + "\n")
 outfile.write(str(kilometers) + "\n")
 outfile.write(str(gallons) + "\n")
 outfile.write(str(liters) + "\n")
 outfile.write(str(pounds) + "\n")
 outfile.write(str(kilograms) + "\n")
 #close the file
 outfile.close()
 print("Data written to conversions.txt")
 #call the main function
converting()
```

Comment: tag your question with python. And python works with indentation so make sure you have properly indended your code within if/else/for etc which i dont see.

Comment: no my indentions are correct on my notepad because it works when I dont use the except error statements. the error on my indents according to my cmd prompt is my else handling on the conversion miles to kilometers @almasshaikh

Comment: It's hard to find error specially when you have huge code pasted. So may be you could narrow it down and paste specific code then.

Comment: «my indentions are correct on my notepad» does not imply that your indentation is correct in the code you pasted into your Q, have you checked it accurately (not in your notepad, but in the Q)?

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt is telling you exactly what's wrong...

Your indentation is wrong, you have different amounts of indentation in different parts of the program.
In Python indentation matters, so you will need to go through your program and see that you have the right amount of spaces. Normally one level of indentation is 4 spaces. Most Python editors will handle this for you.

And your indentation fault is that your `except ValueError` is one space wrong to the left:

```
 if counter <= 3:
   kilometers= miles * 1.6 
   print(miles , "miles is",  kilometers , "kilometers")
  except ValueError:
   print("Error: Miles must be an integer")
```

Start by making the indentation right, it will help your error searching for the rest of the program.

The `range` function you are using will set i in to 0,1,2...9 so it will run 10 times.

In your `write` function `miles` (and the others) are not defined because they are defined in another function, in another scope, so your `display` function cannot reach them, hence the error.